# TypeScript type for object of objects?

Tags: typescript

What would be the correct typescript type of something like

```
const test: MyType = {
  foo: { value: 1 },
  bar: { value: 2 }
}
```

something like

```
type MyType {
  [key: any]: {
    value:number
  }
}
```

results in

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'foo' does not exist in type
```

Comment: Your question doesn't seem right, your type signature is not declared properly and would actually give you `An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'` error even if it was declared properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An index signature parameter type must be either `string` or `number`:

```
type MyType = {
    [key: string]: { value: number; };
};

const test: MyType = {
    foo: { value: 1 },
    bar: { value: 2 }
};
```

Or, using [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype):

```
const test: Record<string, { value: number }> = {
    foo: { value: 1 },
    bar: { value: 2 }
}

const test: Record<'foo' | 'bar', { value: number }> = {
    foo: { value: 1 },
    bar: { value: 2 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const test: Record<string, {value: number}> = {
    foo: { value: 1 },
    bar: { value: 2 }
};
```

Comment: You could add some more info explaining why a record should be used instead of a type.